# How can I take values ​from a table column into an array? (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some table with data (attached image). The goal is to get all the data in a column
**Total working days in this month** into an array in this form:
[tabel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6pXu.png)

```
xVal: int[] = [10,19,19,17,14];
```

These are my components:

**expect-next-month.component.html**

```
        <table id="users">
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{col}}
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let sum of totalWorkPerMonth">
                <td *ngFor="let col of index">
                    {{sum[col]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <button class="myButton" value="get a forecast" type="submit"
                (click)="checkButton(sum.total_packing)">get a forecast</button>
```

As you can see, I tried to link the click event to a function checkButton To get the values ​​from the above column (I'm not sure this is the way)

**expect-next-month.component.ts**

```
  checkButton()//get some array with all the values 
  {
    //some code
  }
```

I know how to take a value from a table when the button is part of the table itself and then you can get the value from the row where the button is (I did this in another code in the above project) but here the button is external, how can you get these values ​​into an array or list?

Thanks for the reference.

Comment: can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) it will help to get what you need.

Comment: I do'nt know if this is relevant, but the goal is basically to get the last two columns into an array so I can perform all sorts of validations on them. I transfer the two arrays with the above columns from the table to a server where it does the validations and returns the result to me.
My function exists, but I just need to get these two arrays from the table and I'm not sure how to do that